# Excel Formula to paste A x B pattern

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have two columns A and B like below

column A contains 1,2,3,4,5 and B contains a,b,c,d,e

I want in column C like 1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,2a,2b,2c,2d,2e,3a,3b and so on.

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/106156/how-can-i-create-a-cross-join-in-excel)

Comment: There is no reason for downvote. Seems to be interesting question.

Comment: @pnuts Yes Formulas qualify as a type of code. But OP is simply a requirements dump, showing no effort or attempts to solve. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results".

Comment: @pnuts I'll say it again: Formulas _are_ a type of code.  Asking for a formula _is_ asking for code.  Not showing any effort, attempts to solve etc _is_ off topic for the reason chosen.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for the acknowledgement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula.

`=CONCATENATE((INDIRECT("A"&ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))),(INDIRECT("B"& IF((ROW()-(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/5,0)*5))=0,5,(ROW()-(ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/5,0)*5))))))`

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you meant by 2a,2b,2c and so on but if all you wanted to do is join what is in column A with what is in column B, this should work:

=CONCATENATE((INDIRECT("A"&ROW())),(INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))

That will give you 1a for C1, 2b for C2 and so on. If you wanted an iterative combination of the first cell in the first column and ALL the other cells from the second column you'd have to throw a loop together with the active/used cells from the second column as the loop end point, and change ROW()+N in the second INDIRECT function call. Then, string that together because now it would be a long text string.

Comment: I want cross join. C column should be like this 1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,2a,2b,2c,2d,2e,3a,3b,3c,3d,3e,4a,4b,4c,4d,4e,5a,5b,5c,5d,5e